# Is EJB inheritance through different EJB modules possible?

Tags: jakarta-ee, eclipselink

Is it possible to have an entity class which inherits from another (abstract) entity class from another ejb module?

EclipseLink for example doesn't create the depending columns in database table of the subclass. It simply ignores the (abstract) superclass entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotation `@Entity` didn't work in my project but the annotation `@MappedSuperclass` which is also part of JPA 1.0 now works very well.